# scrape url from google search using r httr

Tags: xml, r, rcurl, httr

I would like to get the URL from a Google websearch as follows:

```
library(httr)
search.term="httr+package+daterange:%3A2456294-2456659"
url.name=paste0("https://www.google.com/search?q=",search.term)
url.get=GET(url.name)
url.content=content(url.get)
```

Then the attempt to get the links out of the result fails:

```
links <- xpathApply(url.content, "//h3//a[@href]", function(x) xmlAttrs(x)[[1]])
Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "XMLDocumentContent"
```

What is the best method of getting the links out of the url.content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `content()` with `as="text"` to prevent it from returning an object of class `XMLDocumentContent`:

```
library(httr)
search.term="httr+package+daterange:%3A2456294-2456659"
url.name=paste0("https://www.google.com/search?q=",search.term)
url.get=GET(url.name)
url.content=content(url.get, as="text")
links <- xpathSApply(htmlParse(url.content), "//a/@href")
head(links,3)
# href 
# "https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww" 
# href 
# "https://www.google.com/search?q=httr%2Bpackage%2Bdaterange::2456294-2456659&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi" 
# href 
# "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=httr%2Bpackage%2Bdaterange::2456294-2456659&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&sa=N&tab=wl"
```

**Update:**

As Jake points out in a comment, this also works:

```
url.get=GET(url.name)
links <- xpathSApply(htmlParse(url.get), "//a/@href")
```

Comment: you can also `htmlParse(url.get)` and skip `content` altogether

Comment: true, @JakeBurkhead. :)

Comment: You should be able to do `xpathSApply(content(url.get), "//a/@href")`. Typically I'd also add `stop_for_status(url.get)` so you know immediately if the HTTP request failed (as opposed to the html parsing failing)

Comment: And the reason it doesn't work out of the box is that there's something screwy with the classes in the XML package, vs what I'm returning from `content()`. I filed an issue at https://github.com/hadley/httr/issues/66

Comment: @lukeA - thanks, it works! 

hadley - xpathSApply(content(url.get), "//a/@href")
 produces: Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
  no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "XMLDocumentContent"

Comment: one can also use useInternalNode=T with httpParseTree function to make the scraping work ..  for e.g xmlparsed<-httpParseTree(url,useInternalNode=T) and then xpathSApply(xmlparsed,"//a/@href",xmlValue) will do the same